# Not simulating 'change' using enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a Reactjs component and it has one button and a date-range picker.
I want to simulate onclick and onchange events of button and picker respectively.
I'm able to simulate onclick of the button. but on change of datepicker is not working

I have tried this

```
headerComponent.find(`#prev_button`).at(1).simulate("click");
headerComponent.find(`#dropdown`).at(1).simulate("change", { value: "t" });
```

please see this sandbox [click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-bush-zyv7h?file=/src/tests/index.test.js) for full code and test file

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Enzyme documentation](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.html) you make a mistake on your second argument on `simulate` function.

To simulate changes on the input, you should change it like this  :

```
headerComponent.find(`#dropdown`).at(1).simulate("change", { target: { value: "t" } });
```

Comment: still it is not working. can you try in the sandbox ? @marzzy

Answer (score 0):

Testing with enzyme is tricky. You should try not to test dependencies because you trust those [are already tested](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/date-picker/__tests__/RangePicker.test.js). Having said that, you could shallow render instead of mounting and look for the `RangePicker` component in the shallow tree, get the handler you are passing in the `onChange` prop and call it manually, then check the callback prop you pass to your component is called with the expected value.

```
describe.only("test", () => {
  it("should render", () => {
    const callBackToSetDates = jest.fn();
    const callBackToSetFilter = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <Header
        {...headerProps1}
        callBackToSetDates={callBackToSetDates}
        callBackToSetFilter={callBackToSetFilter}
      />
    );
    const rangePickerOnChange = wrapper.find("RangePicker").prop("onChange");
    rangePickerOnChange("someValue");
    expect(callBackToSetDates).toHaveBeenCalledWith("someValue");
  });
});
```

the purpose is to test only the logic you add inside your component, i.e., you transform the value you get from the RangePicker to something else

```
        <RangePicker
          ...
          onChange={(value) => {
             callBackToSetDates(`I'm transforming ${value}`);
          }}
        />
```

and in your test

```
    rangePickerOnChange("someValue");
    expect(callBackToSetDates).toHaveBeenCalledWith("I'm transforming someValue");
```

you can see it working here https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-rosalind-uec6t?file=/src/tests/index.test.js

If you really want to keep testing what the actual user sees, you'll need to fire the events that the user does when using the component. In this case: you need to click the input, look for a date, click it, then click another date to completely fire the `onChange` event of the `RangePicker` component. You might look at how [antd test it](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/date-picker/__tests__/RangePicker.test.js) and copy the necessary jest configuration they have to mock some DOM APIs